# C - Want to convert lowercase and uppercase letters using symbols

Tags: c

I want to convert lowercase letters to uppercase and vice versa in C. I already do that but when I use a symbol like '_' or '.' or ',' .... on the input I get random character on the output like a question mark inside a square.

> INPUT: AAbb
>   OUTPUT: aaBB
>   INPUT: a_A
>   OUTPUT: A⍰a

How can I make this work with symbols?

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    char a[50];
    int x = 1;

    while( x > 0){
        gets(a);
        int i,length=0;
        for(i=0;a[i]!='\0';i++)
            length+=1;
        for(i=0;i<length;i++){
            a[i]=a[i]^32;
        }
        printf("%s",&a);
    }
}
```

Comment: @spectras, it is C++, it won't compile as C.

Comment: @SidS I hesitated quite a bit, since author wrote "C" in title and in question explicitly, and uses mostly C idioms. I went for C because of this: fixing it to run in C seemed closer to the intent than making it a C++-style program. — **[update:]** well it turns out he just edited the C tag back, so that really is the intent :)

Comment: @spectras, Ok.  Not that big a deal.

Comment: BTW, there's no need for two `for` loops there - just use `a[i] != 0` as your loop condition when swapping case.  `length` is unnecessary.

Comment: insert the statement: `#include <ctype.h>`   Then make use of the `toupper()` and `tolower()` facilities.  Then the alphabet will be processed and any other characters will remain unchanged

Answer (score 3):

> ... convert lowercase and uppercase letters using symbols
>   ... when I use a symbol like '_' or '.' or ',' .... on the input I get random character

Use `isupper()`, `tolower()`, `toupper()`.  This is the **standard** and highly **portable** way to toggle case.  Consider there are more than 26 letters on various platforms.

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void ){
  char a[50];
  {
    gets(a);   // dubious, consider fgets().
    int i,length=0;

    for(i=0;a[i];i++){
      unsigned char ch = a[i];
      if (isupper(ch) {
        a[i]= tolower(ch);
      } else {
        a[i]= toupper(ch);
      }
    }
    printf("%s",a);  // use `a` , not `&a`
  }
}
```

---

If code wants to toggle case without using standard function, and knowns the `char` is a letter, code could use the following.  It reasonably assumes that A-Z and a-z differ by one bit as is the case in [ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) and [EBCDIC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EBCDIC)

```
        // Avoid magic numbers like 32
        a[i] ^= 'a' ^ 'A';
```

Still recommend to use standard functions.

Answer (score 2):

Don't change anything you don't want to change.

Replace :

```
a[i]=a[i]^32;
```

with

```
if (a[i] >= 'A' && a[i] <= 'Z' ||
    a[i] >= 'a' && a[i] <= 'z')
{
    a[i] = a[i] ^ 32;
}
```

If you `#include <ctype.h>` you can do it like this:

```
a[i] = islower(a[i]) ? toupper(a[i])
                     : tolower(a[i]);
```

Answer (score 1):

The C Standard specifies functions in `<ctype.h>` to handle case for the basic character set:

- `islower(c)` tests if the character is lower-case
- `isupper(c)` tests if the character is upper-case
- `tolower(c)` converts any character to its lower-case version
- `toupper(c)` converts any character to its upper-case version

Here is how to use these:

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    char a[50];

    if (fgets(a, sizeof a, stdin)) {
        int i;
        for (i = 0; a[i] != '\0'; i++) {
            unsigned char c = a[i];
            a[i] = islower(c) ? toupper(c) : tolower(c);
        }
        printf("%s", a);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Nice and clean.

Answer (score -2):

You can't. See ascii table. What differs from an uppercase letter from a lowercase letter is the bit 5 00100000b, which is equivalent in decimal to 32. 
But this only works with letters.

You should put ifs to treat anything that is not a letter.